# how can i find the tr with specific id and these ids comming from database dynamically...?

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

I have data in the form of a table. The data is coming from a database. Each row is assigned a dynamic ID coming from the database.

How can I select that row with specific ID and then be able to style that whole row, using jquery?

This is the data coming from the database:
[image]

Comment: How are you determining "that row"?  That signifies the starting point.  Without that, we really can't suggest how to proceed from the vague question.  Also if the rows have dynamic ids, using the id to style is possibly a poor solution.  It may be better to dynamically build your rows with expected classes which apply the styles you want.  Then no javascript needed.

Comment: you mean you want the user to click on the row and then it changes style, to show it is currently selected?

Comment: You might want to consider to use DataTables (https://datatables.net/). It is an excellent jQuery plugin which can almost anything you possibly want. Just to prevent you from reinventing the weel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this into foreach or similar loop:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $database_row_id; ?>">...</tr>
```

Where `$database_row_id` is the `id` you get from database

Answer (score 0):

You can generate table rows dynamically using php

```
for( $database_rows as $row ){
    echo "<tr id=\"{$row->id}\">" . _content_of_row_ ."</tr>";
}
```

Yes you can use jQuery to do that.

for example if your generated row be like below

`<tr id="31"> .... </tr>`

you can select the row like this

`$("tr#31")`

then you can add css class to it:

`$("tr#31").addClass("selected")`

remove css class from it:

`$("tr#31").removeClass("selected")`

add attributes to it:

`$("tr#31").attr("attribute", "value")`

or anything else.